# Transit Visa for UK with Refugee Travel Permit

Tags: uk, transit-visas, british-airways

I am flying from Zürich to Oman via British airways and it will make a stop in Heathrow airport to change the flight (Arrival & Departure from the same terminal).

I have Swiss Blue Passport (Travel Document) which is issued to Refugees for travel purposes.

Do I need a Transit visa for this short time period of entry in UK or is the Swiss Travel document enough?

Comment: You may need a [Direct Airside Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/transit/somewhere_else/no) if your country of origin is on the linked list. While your question is slightly different, my close vote takes you to a TSE answer and links to the [UK widget](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/transit-visas) for the official info.

Answer (score -1):

What you have is a Home office travel Document issued by the Swiss govt and as such I do not think you would need a transit visa [(reference)](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa)

> You don’t need a transit visa if you:
>
> are from the European Economic area (EEA) or Switzerland
>
> have an EEA family permit
>
> have a Home Office travel document, for example you’re a
> refugee or stateless person
>
> have a Standard Visitor visa
>
> have a Marriage Visitor visa

Comment: Could you summarise the reference in case the link breaks?

Comment: When you downvote, its good manners to state the reason for the downvote. I did add a summary as a user suggested to my answer but that is not sufficient ground for a downvote.

Comment: OP may need a [Direct Airside Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/transit/somewhere_else/no), depending on their country of origin. OP would not have a Home office travel document, as it was not issued by the UK Home Office. It would be a Swiss travel document.

Comment: @Giorgio The direct airside transit visa seems to be if he is switching airplanes in the UK. A home office travel document from what i understood is a document issued by the home offices in each country. He has one issued by the Swiss home office. The OP does not plan to leave the airport in any case.